# How can I supply a Bash variable to Python's getpass()?

Tags: python, mysql, bash

I am calling a Python script supplied as part of a package from a Bash script I wrote, which calls the script in addition to doing various other things. Specifically, earlier on in the Bash script, I use a Zenity password dialog to get the user's MySQL root password and store it in a Bash variable to do some database setup. Later on, the Python script is called, and it too wants the user's MySQL root password.

I tried simply reusing the variable containing the password by using a pipe and a here string, but neither works; the script simply hangs there until I return to the terminal and enter the password again. I dug a bit into the Python script and found it uses [getpass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) to ask for the password. Is there any way I can give it the password from the previously-created Bash variable so that I only have to ask the user for it once through a GUI?

Comment: Is it your script? can you alter it to get the password as an argument?

Comment: Try to search for `expect` solutions.

Comment: @Korem No, it's not mine. It's actually from an older version of ERPNext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the information is allready present in a bash variable (say the name is `pwd`), IMHO the simplest solution is to export it  to the environment.

```
export pwd
```

Then you can get it in the Python script :

```
pwd = os.environ('pwd')
```